# How to calculate kml LatLonBox from corner coordinates?

Tags: kml, geocoding

I have corner coordinates for my image

```
upperleft  lat/lon 80.5434057263 -35.6660101669 
lowerleft  lat/lon 74.8586568503 -16.5889844463 
upperright lat/lon 83.3580195158 16.0865335458
lowerright lat/lon 76.4500836068 12.9849754068
```

For a [ground overlay in a kml-file](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#ground_overlays), there is coordinates with a rotation, but I somehow cannot see how to get from the above to this one:

```
<LatLonBox>
    <north>????</north>
    <south>????</south>
    <east>????</east>
    <west>????</west>
    <rotation>????</rotation>
</LatLonBox>
```

I guess some of you have done this before? Or is there a way of using corner coordinates?

Comment: What happes when you set rotation to `0`?

Comment: that won't work since it assumes the upper edge to be lined up at 80 degree. But one corner at 80, the other at 76, so there is a rotation ...

Comment: Are you sure about the coordinates? The single negative looks wrong. Other than that, its just going to be some trig (assume its on a Cartesian plane).

Comment: oh, you were right, typo in the coordinates ... corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems I in part can answer my own question: I [found in the reference pages](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#gxlatlonquad) that kml allows me to use corner coordinates using LatLonQuad

```
<GroundOverlay>
  <name>gx:LatLonQuad Example2</name>
  <Icon>
        <href>Z:/RS2_20140830_074631_0076_SCWA_HHHV_SGF_344973_4404_9908279_Cal_Spk_reproj_EPSG3575_HH.jpg</href
  </Icon>
  <gx:LatLonQuad>
    <coordinates>
     -16.5889844463,74.8586568503 12.9849754068,76.4500836068 16.0865335458,83.3580195158 -35.6660101669,80.5434057263
    </coordinates>
  </gx:LatLonQuad>
</GroundOverlay>
```

I assume that this method is equivalent to the LatLonBox above, except using corner coordinates instead